# Sublime Text, my file is stored in my home folder when I write a file using fstream on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, fstream

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on mac to write c++. I wrote some code that gets my cin value for the name and the age and write them in the file file.txt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int age;
    ofstream file("file.txt", ios::out);
    cout<<"enter name: "<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"enter age: "<<endl;
    cin>>age;
    file<<name<<" "<<age<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that "file.txt" file is stored in my home folder, not my current working directory.
how can I store it in my current working directory?
[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqLzL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too weird problem, I'm not 100% fully sure about macOS, but this works on Linux and Windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void) {
    std::ofstream file("./file.txt", std::ios::out); // --- here add './' prefix
    std::string name;
    int age;

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name); // use std::getline() for whitespaces

    std::cout << "Your age: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    file << name << ' ' << age << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Just add `./` before the file name to explicitly define the output directory of the file must the same where the program is actually running.

### Another solution

If the aforementioned solution fails, try `g++ -o your_program your_program.cpp` and run the program again. If it works successfully as you expect, it's cleared that something's wrong in your Sublime Text settings.

Comment: Try to run `g++ -o your_program your_program.cpp` and run it there then see if it works (manual method). If it works for you, it'll be cleared that something's going wrong with Sublime Text settings.

Comment: oh it worked! I guess something is wrong with sublime text project setting but I don't know the commands to fix.. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: There is no reason this code would behave any differently than the OPs code, it will save to the current working directory as will the OPs code.

Comment: The `working_dir` key in your `sublime-build` file specifies what the working directory should be set to when the build executes.